# How does a package like fabric (written in python) make its CLI tool fab

Tags: python, command-line-interface, fabric

I got curious about making command line tools in python (without having to type `python tool.py`)

I know fabric does this so I started looking through their github page and I couldn't track down where the `fab` tool actually comes from.

1. How do they do it?
2. What is a minimal way to get a tool like this working?

https://github.com/fabric/fabric

Comment: in Linux if you add `shebang` (ie. `#!/usr/bin/env python`) in first line and set `execution attrib` (`chmod +x script.py`) then you can run directly `script.py` instead `python script.py`. You can even remove extension `.py`

Comment: I suspected that and I thought I tried it on osx but it didn't work....I'll try it again when at my computer

Comment: `shebang` has to be in first line, it has to start with `#!` (`#` = she, `!` = bang). And it needs `excution attrib` to work. OSX should work similar to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Skipping the command line part as that's a different story and only focusing on where the fab.exe is coming from as you made me curious.)

It's from setup.py, the interesting part is:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'fab = fabric.main:main',
        ]
},
```

which tells what it actually starts.

To reproduce, here's an almost empty setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='consoletest',
    version='1.1',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'consoletest = consoletest.main:main',
        ]
    },
)
```

Please create a subdir `consoletest` and put in it an empty `__init__.py` (to tell it's a module) plus a `main.py` with the following content:

```
def main():
    print("hello")
```

then issue

```
python setup.py install
```

in the root, and if everything went well, an egg file will be created in python's Lib/site-packages directory, and a `consoletest` executable in the Scripts dir. (Tested only under Windows/Python 2.7 so you may not get the same result.)

Now if you start `consoletest` it will print hello.